# Increasing web server performance

Tags: rest, tomcat, webserver, high-load

What configuration should I usually set to increase web server performance ? (For example Apache TomCat). I need that my web server process a lot of requests at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Facebook Hip Hop.
Or just try to use cache e.g in Redis

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve webserver performance, there are a few steps to follow.

- Implement a high performance reverse proxy, like nginx.
- Let nginx to handle all static content delivery.
- Handle Secure Socket Layers negotiation in nginx because SSL and TLS traffic encryption uses CPU time and memory.
- Make your content compression (gzip) in nginx.

Resuming, you have to avoid assigning tasks to your webserver, other than handle dynamic content, and backend processing tasks.

PD: You can also take a look to [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/intro/index.html#intro).